# Why we need empty constructor in JPA. ??

Tags: jpa

Now , I'm learning JPA. JPA recommend we must have Public method and private field and no static and final with variable. and also empty constructor .. Why we need this format.???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually specification does not recommend, it is rather normative about following (among other things):

1. public or protected no-arg constructor must exist. Additional constructors are fine.
2. Persistent fields should not be public (protected, package visible and private are  aloud).
3. Final persistent attributes or methods are not aloud.

Some reasons for those restrictions are:

1. JPA provider needs to create instances of entity. If class would contain only constructor which takes arbitrary arguments, JPA provider cannot figure out values for those arguments.
2. Probably public visibility is simply not aloud because fields should not be directly accessed from outside of class. Or maybe there is better reason, but I an not aware of that.
3. Provider wants to create proxy, and it is not possible if methods are final. Also attributes should not be final, because then provider cannot assign value to them.

Additionally static persistent attribute does not make too much sense, because why would one value be shared by all instances of entity.